# Idiomatic IO with scala

Tags: scala, jvm

In java, common IO operations involving streams, files and the like can be somewhat annoying. Thus I (and many others) tend to reach for things like commons-io to ease the pain.

In scala - are there some better idioms/classes/libraries to use (I know of scala.io.Source etc for reading in text files - but what about streams etc). Is it "normal" to use libraries like commons-io in scala or is there a much better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were some discussions on the Scala mailing list on this particular matter.  And, if I recall correctly, nothing concrete came out of them.  In the mean time, you won't be at a loss to check out [Scalax](http://scalax.scalaforge.org/).  scalax.io looks very promising.

Comment: Is the link above out of date ? When I access it, it simply says "It doesn't work!"

Answer (score 5):

What about using:

```
Source.fromInputStream(is, "UTF8")
```

As in:

```
for (line <- Source.fromInputStream(is, "UTF8").getLines) {
   // process line here
}
```

Comment: Yes I knew about that but its only suitable for text/source files, its not a general IO api.

Comment: @michael -you asked specifically about anything in scala to handle IO with streams. I really don't think the answer deserves the downvote. It's perfectly legitimate to use this with any underlying textual stream (eg from a socket).

Answer (score 1):

I/O hasn't been addressed as yet in Scala. What exists, exists solely to support the compiler and the XML library.

Answer (score 0):

Erik Engbrecht's scalax [fork](http://github.com/eengbrec/Scalax.IO/tree/scala-2.8.0-improvements) might be useful.